# How to optimize the size of a pdf generated with JasperExportManager and JRFileVirtualizer

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I generate a PDF in java with this method:

```
...
JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(2, sTempPath);
virtualizer.setReadOnly(false);
map.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);
map.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.ITALIAN);

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map, conn.getConnection());
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, reportNameSaveTo);
...
```

now I have to optimize the size by setting a "compression" to the pdf, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.compressed=true in jasperreports.properties, or do something equivalent in [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509688/how-to-compress-pdf-in-jasperreports).

Comment: jasperreports.properties is for jasper report server?
I'm not running on jasperserver and I'm not using JRPdfExporter jrPdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
I use JasperExportManager

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, JasperExportManager anyways [uses](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperExportManager.html#exportToPdfFile%28java.lang.String%29) a JRPdfExporter instance to export to pdf, which is configured using parameters from jasperreports.properties. It works when for me when I use jasperreports from your java code.